# Php preg_match - Get specif value

Tags: php, preg-match

How can I get the string: pL427014992694557 using preg_match in the code below? the function name inside the document.write can variate Ex: xS427014992694557 or nH927014992694557

```
R$document.write(pL427014992694557())
```

Tks

Comment: What have you tried? Have you read the documentation for [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) yet?

Comment: Yes... im trying with the code   if (preg_match('/R$document.write((0-9)(/', $page, $matches)){
   echo $matches[1];
  }

Comment: Put the code you tried in your question. Also say why it doesnt work and post the error, if any.

Comment: You need to escape the literal `(` characters.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can gather, you want a lower case letter, an upper case letter, then 14 numbers.

```
$subject = "pL427014992694557";
$pattern = '/[a-z][A-Z][0-9]{14}/';
preg_match($pattern, $subject, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$source = 'R$document.write(pL427014992694557())';
preg_match("/^[^(]+[(]([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/", $source, $match);
echo $match[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

I have do it using preg_match. my code is given below

```
<?php
ob_start();
?>
<script type="text/javascript">document.write(pL427014992694557');</script>
<?php
$offset = ob_get_clean();
$kt =  strip_tags($offset);
$pattern = "/document\.write\('([^)]*)'\)/";
preg_match($pattern, $kt, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
?>
```

My Output

```
sample
```